Find all possible Jordan forms of a real matrix $A$ of order 7 whose minimal and characteristic polynomial is $(x-2)^3(x+3)^2$ and $(x-2)^4(x+3)^3$
Our professor recently taught us minimal polynomial in a Linear Algebra course. At the end of his lecture, he wrote on board just how does a Jordan matrix looks like and told us to consider that as the apparent "definition" for the same. He didn't teach us anything in 'detail' about Jordan matrices whatsoever.( Of course the lecture was coming to an end.) Neither the word, "generalized eigenspaces" was mentioned (, and honestly I myself don't know what that term means but in linear algebra books I saw in the sections that dealt with Jordan Canonical forms the word was mentioned frequently and that's why I mentioned it in here thinking that it might be an integral part of the concept.)
He then gave us the question written below:
Find all possible Jordan forms of a real matrix $A$ of order $7$ whose minimal polynomial is $(x-2)^3(x+3)^2$ and characteristic polynomial is $(x-2)^4(x+3)^3.$
He expected us to solve it. But I literally have no idea on how to go about it. Can anyone provide me with a working procedure for solving these sort of problems? I am having a hard time dealing with this problem, for I don't understand how to proceed.

The following facts might be helpful:

The diagonal elements of a Jordan block must, of course, be eigen values $\lambda$ (repeated as many times as the power of $x-\lambda)$ in the characteristic polynomial).
The maximum size of a block with the eigen value $\lambda$ is simply the power of $(x-\lambda)$ in the minimal polynomial and there must be one such block.

Thus, the Jordan block for the given scenario must contain four $2$'s and three $-3$'s on the diagonal. The maximum size of the Jordan block with eigen value $2$ is $3\times 3$. And the maximum size of the Jordan block with eigen value $-3$ is $2\times 2$.
Thus, there must be a $3\times 3$ Jordan block with eigen value $2$. It looks like $\begin{pmatrix} 2&1&0\\0&2&1\\0&0&2\end{pmatrix}$
Remaining one $2$ should be accommodated by a single block $(2)$. In the same fashion, there must be a $2\times 2$ Jordan block containing eigen value $-3$ which is $\begin{pmatrix} -3&1\\0&-3\end{pmatrix}$. The remaining one $3$ must be accomodated in $(-3)$. Hence, the only possible Jordan form is
$$\begin{pmatrix} 
2&1&0&0&0&0&0\\
0&2&1&0&0&0&0\\
0&0&2&0&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&2&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&0&-3&1&0\\
0&0&0&0&0&-3&0\\
0&0&0&0&0&0&-3\\
\end{pmatrix}$$
In fact, the number of blocks with respect to an eigen value is its geometric multiplicity. Here, the geometric multiplicity was not given. We guessed based on minimal and characteristic polynomial. Now, we can easily conclude that geometric multiplicities of $2$ and $-3$ are $2$.
$\textbf{Edit }$
Let me explain how one would find the Jordan form of any given matrix. Suppose $p(x)$ is the characteristic polynomial of a matrix $A$ over a field $\mathbb{F}$ and with minimal polynomial $m(x)$. Suppose, $p(x)$ has got all its roots in the field $\mathbb{F}$. Let $\lambda_1, \dots, \lambda_k$ be the eigen values of $A$ with algebraic multiplicities $a_1, \dots, a_k$. Then the characteristic polynomial would be
$$p(x)= (x-\lambda_1)^{a_1}\dots (x-\lambda_k)^{a_k}.$$
Suppose the minimal polynomial is
$$m(x)= (x-\lambda)^{b_1}\dots(x-\lambda)^{b_k}.$$
Also, suppose the geometric multiplicities of the eigen values are $g_1, \dots, g_k$, respectively.
Then the Jordan form of $A$ is constructed under the following guidelines:

The maximum size of Jordan block with respect to the eigen value $\lambda_i$ is $b_i\times b_i$.
The number of blocks with respect to eigen value $\lambda_i$ is $g_i$.
Number of times $\lambda_i$ can appear is $a_i$.

$\textbf{For example}$
Let $p(x) = (x-2)^4(x-1)^5$ and $m(x)=(x-2)^2(y-2)^3$. Now, the eigen values are $2$ and $1$. To decide the number of Jordan blocks, we do not have geometric multiplicities of the eigen values. But, we know that the maximum size of Jordan blocks containing $2$ is $2\times 2$ and for $1$ it is $3\times 3$.
Now, there must be four $2'$s on the diagonal. Under the given constrain, we must have a $2\times 2$ block $\begin{pmatrix} 2&1\\0&2\end{pmatrix}$. We can now repeat one more such block or we can have two $1\times 1$ blocks $(2)$.
Thus there are two possibilities with respect to $2$.
At the same time, we have two possibilities for blocks containing $1$:
One $3\times 3 $ block with either a $2\times 2$ block or two $1\times 1$ block.
Now totally, we can now have $4$ unsimilar Jordan forms.

Thank you for your answer! But can you consider adding a detailed explanation. Without working out an example, this seems a little confusing, imho... I will be grateful if you consider adding a bit more details regarding how many Jordan blocks will be there?How should they be arranged? etc

Okay. Edited...

I have further edited with another example
